# How to decode hex to negative integer value in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, hex

I have the following hex data format:

```
9BDCE310
B4D9F1E502
EAB1A9C607
88EE8EB9F9FFFFFFFF01
9E828D89FCFFFFFFFF01
```

Normally, I using the following code to decode back to integer:

```
sub decodeInt
{
    $_[0] =~ s/^([\x80-\xFF]*[\x00-\x7F])// or return;

    my $encoded_num = $1;
    my $num = 0;
    for ( reverse unpack 'C*', $encoded_num )
    {
        $num = ( $num << 7 ) | ( $_ & 0x7F );
    }

    return $num;
}
```

But it didn't work with the signed negative integer value (the last 2 data).

```
88EE8EB9F9FFFFFFFF01
9E828D89FCFFFFFFFF01
```

Please help me modify the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the decoded value is a 64-bit signed two's-complement ints cast to unsigned. On a two's complement machine, you can cast it back using the following:

```
$num = unpack 'q', pack 'Q', $num;
```

For example,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use Config qw( %Config );

sub decode_int {
    my ($encoded_num) = @_;

    my $num = 0;
    $num = ( $num << 7 ) | ( $_ & 0x7F )
       for reverse unpack 'C*', $encoded_num;

    $num = unpack 'q', pack 'Q', $num;

    return $num;
}

{
   $Config{ivsize} >= 8 && $Config{uvsize} >= 8
      or die("64-bit int support required\n");

   say decode_int(pack('H*', $_))
      for qw(
         9BDCE310
         B4D9F1E502
         EAB1A9C607
         88EE8EB9F9FFFFFFFF01
         9E828D89FCFFFFFFFF01
      );
}
```

outputs

```
35188251
750546100
2026526954
-1759267064
-1054654178
```

Note that the encoding scheme used is very inefficient for signed numbers.

Comment: Outstanding, work very well. You help my task again.